# How to Use Two or More Model Class as Data source in Crystal Report C# WinForms

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crystal-reports

My Question is My company got a project that was handled by another company. they used CrystalReport for reporting. Project is a C# WinForms Application That uses crystal Report 13 and entity framework with SQL server.

Assume that there is a class called customer. I was able to get a Customer Report using crystal report by setting up the report's data source as follows and design the report using model class.

rpt.setDatasource(dbcontext.customers.toList());

BUT

if class has a relationship with another class for an example

customer -> Sale

How Can I pass a List of sales and sale's customer details both as a data source using entity framework? .

I also tried making a new model that containing the Customer Object and List of Sales object. But in designing of the report, I cant navigate to them since they are custom types.

Comment: If your Customer entity has a collection of Sales, then you can eager-load them using `rpt.SetDatasource(dbcontext.Customers.Include(c=>c.Sales).ToList());` If it doesn't have a reference to it's Sales, then consider adding that relationship. The more difficult aspect though may be refreshing the report designer data source. Typically from memory this was done via XML schemas. It's been too long since I've had to mess around with Crystal reports to provide specifics but this should get you started: http://aspalliance.com/2049_Use_LINQ_to_Retrieve_Data_for_Your_Crystal_Reports.2

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I will try it today. but I am wondering how to design the report. should I need to add models separately and design the report then use eager loading to assign data source ?.

Comment: When working with relational data where you have a list of customers then within each customer a list of sales, that would likely involve creating a sub-report for the Sales linked to the applicable customer ID.

Comment: any reference for doing like that. I have no clue about where to start. I tried using adding models separately but it doesn't work. thank you.